# Update data in sheet cells from userform textbox

Tags: vba, user-interface

I have this code that transfers data to a sheet and creates a data base of : Name, DOB, Phone number, Insurance name, Insurance ID.

```
Dim strDataRange As Range
Dim keyRange As Range
Set strDataRange = Range("A1:h5000")
Set keyRange = Range("A1:h5000")
strDataRange.Sort Key1:=keyRange, Header:=xlYes
Dim tr As Worksheet
Set tr = Worksheets("Sheet16")
iRow = tr.Cells(Rows.Count, 1) _
.End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
tr.Cells(iRow, 1).Value = Me.TextBox1.Value
tr.Cells(iRow, 2).Value = Me.TextBox2.Value
tr.Cells(iRow, 3).Value = Me.TextBox22.Value
tr.Cells(iRow, 4).Value = Me.TextBox23.Value
tr.Cells(iRow, 5).Value = Me.TextBox17.Value
tr.Cells(iRow, 6).Value = Me.ComboBox15.Value
tr.Cells(iRow, 7).Value = Me.TextBox21.Value
tr.Cells(iRow, 8).Value = Me.TextBox32.Value
```

Then on this code, I am able to call all that information enter before (above code) and its populates on textboxes:

```
Private Sub ComboBox13_Change()
On Error Resume Next
Me.TextBox1.Value = Me.ComboBox13.Column(0)
Me.TextBox2.Value = Me.ComboBox13.Column(1)
Me.TextBox22.Value = Me.ComboBox13.Column(2)
Me.TextBox23.Value = Me.ComboBox13.Column(3)
Me.TextBox17.Value = Me.ComboBox13.Column(4)
Me.ComboBox15.Value = Me.ComboBox13.Column(5)
Me.TextBox21.Value = Me.ComboBox13.Column(6)
Me.TextBox32.Value = Me.ComboBox13.Column(7)
On Error GoTo 0
End Sub

With ComboBox13
.ColumnCount = 1
.ColumnWidths = "120"
.ColumnHeads = False
.RowSource = "Sheet16!A2:h5200"
End With
```

What I can't do or I need to do is, If the data change on any of these 
 `enter code here`text boxes and I need to update the information such as 
 : phone 'number or Insurance Id. How can I change it on those text boxes 
 and press a 'command button to update that new data enter?

Thanks a lot

Comment: I think you might want to include some screenshots or provide a little more detail about what you mean with `enter code here` text boxes. If you are using a form to change a row, shouldn't you be able to capture the row integer somewhere?

Comment: if you add a submit button to your form it will commit your textbox changes or any other control changes.  You can write an change sub for some of these controls as well to implement what do do if there is a change, works better with selection though, as a keystroke is a change and a textbox can be many keystrokes.